# P class is empty using find_all even though it is there

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape Kickstarter pages using BeautifulSoup, specifically for the Risks and Challenges section, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapmaker/snapmaker-20-modular-3-in-1-3d-printers")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
project = soup.find("p", {"class" :"js-risks-text text-preline"})
```

I print out the project and it's empty. Can anyone tell me why that's happening? I've checked that the response worked by just calling `find_all` on `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content you are trying to scrape is dynamically rendered in the browser. You can use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapmaker/snapmaker-20-modular-3-in-1-3d-printers")

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
project = soup.find("p", {"class" :"js-risks-text"})
```

Output:

> This is our second Kickstarter
>   campaign. To date, we have delivered over 10,000 units to users in
>   over 100 countries. We are using the same supply base that we
>   established over the past two years through our first product. And we
>   continue to improve our production process and technics process. We’ve
>   also selected the best suppliers in this industry. We feel confident
>   that we will ensure product quality and hit the delivery dates we are
>   providing.
>   
>   The Snapmaker 2.0 is a more complex product than the original model.
>   There could be unexpected risks that can arise during the pilot
>   production. The safety class of the laser module in Snapmaker 2.0 is
>   class 4. We will pay special attention to get FDA/FCC/CE/RoHS
>   certifications in late August, which are necessaries for delivering
>   our products to the US, EU and most areas in the world. When we
>   fulfilled our first Kickstarter campaign, we experienced the hard
>   decision of delaying the mass-production to hold ourselves to high
>   quality and user experience standards. We won’t ship unless our
>   product can meet or exceed these high standards.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the problem of how sometimes soup.find returns None?